# Updating a field in a record dyanamically in extjs

Tags: extjs, gridpanel, extjs4.2

**Scenario**

I want to update the column data of particular record in grid having store with static data.
  Here is my **store**:

```
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model  : 'MyModel',
autoLoad:true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'app/data/data.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users'
    }
},
```

**My data.json**

```
 {
     'users': [{
         QMgrStatus: "active",
         QMgrName: 'R01QN00_LQYV',
         ChannelStatus: 'active',
         ChannelName: 'LQYV.L.CLNT',
         MxConn: 50
     }]
 }
```

**What I am doing to update the record :**

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid');
var store = Ext.getStore('Mystore');
store.each(function(record, idx) {
    val = record.get('ChannelName');
    if (val == "LQYV.L.CLNT") {
        record.set('ChannelStatus', 'inactive');

        record.commit();
    }
});
console.log(store);
grid.getView().refresh();
```

**MY PROBLEM**

I am getting the record updated over here.It is not getting reflected in my grid panel.The grid is using the same old store(static).Is the problem of static data? Or am I missing something or going somewhere wrong? Please help me out with this issue.Thanks a lot.

**MY EDIT**

I am tryng to color code the column based on the status.But here I am always getting the **status="active"** even though I am updating the store.

**What I am trying to do in my grid**

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    itemId: 'InterfaceQueueGrid',
    id: 'MyGrid',
    store: 'Mytore',
    height: 216,
    width: 600,
    columns: [{
        text: 'QueueMgr Status',
        dataIndex: 'QMgrStatus',
        width: 80
    }, {
        text: 'Queue Manager \n Name',
        dataIndex: 'QMgrName',
        width: 138
    }, {
        text: 'Channel Status',
        dataIndex: 'ChannelStatus',
        width: 78,
        align: 'center',
        renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
            var val = record.get('ChannelStatus');
            console.log(val); // Here I am always getting status="active". 
            if (val == 'inactive') {
                return '<img src="redIcon.png"/>';
            } else if (val == 'active') {
                return '<img src="greenIcon.png"/>';
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Channel Name',
        align: 'center',
        dataIndex: 'ChannelName',
        width: 80
    } {
        text: 'Max Connections',
        align: 'center',
        dataIndex: 'MxConn',
        width: 80
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A drastic way is to reconfigure your grid. This may not end up to be your final solution, but maybe you get to know what is going wrong.

Call

```
grid.reconfigure(store)
```

instead of

```
grid.getView().refresh();
```

after changing the records. You can also use a single store.commitChanges() instead of using a record.commit() on each single record.

Comment: Thanks Christoph.
I resolved it using grid.bindStore(MyUpdatedStore);
But your solution also rocks.Thanks a lot

Comment: Used grid.reconfigure(store) - worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it is just a typo, you assign val in your condition. Try this (= to ==):

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid');
var store = Ext.getStore('Mystore');
store.each(function(record,idx){
      val = record.get('ChannelName');
      if(val == "LQYV.L.CLNT"){
         record.set('ChannelStatus','active');
      }
      else {
         record.set('ChannelStatus','inactive');
      }
      record.commit();
});
console.log(store);
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks.But still I am getting the status as inactive.I am still getting the val as inactive in my grid's column renderer.It is taking the old store values.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **commiting** your store and **reloading** it ?

Try this way.

```
yourstorename.commitChanges();
yourstorename.reload();
```

Comment: Thnks Shankar.Please look into my edit.I am not getting values of the store reflected in my grid.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using

```
grid.bindStore(myupdatedstore);
```

As stated by @Christoph

```
grid.reconfigure(store)
```

works fine as well .